# How to make dnsmasq's DHCP server give out arbitrary resolvers?

Tags: 16.04, lxc, dnsmasq

I'm using lxc on Ubuntu 16.04.  Lxc seems to use dnsmasq as the DHCP *and* DNS servers for the containers - have I understood correctly?

How can I make dnsmasq's DHCP server give out 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as the DNS resolvers, instead of giving out its own IP address as the DNS resolver for DHCP clients (the lxc containers)?

(I can't find the dnsmasq configuration that I assume lxc would generate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tested this, but I would *guess* that in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, you need to include a line like:

```
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the problem, there is no `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.  The only config file which I can find is `/etc/dnsmasq.d/lxc` which only contains the lines: `bind-interfaces` and `except-interface=lxcbr0`.

Comment: Many thanks, I *created* the file `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and your solution worked.